# What is bounce rate in google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does google calculate bounce rate?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/how-does-google-calculate-bounce-rate)

I hosted a new site and used google analytics in it. I noticed that they're giving a value called bounce off rate. Can anyone explain what it it?

Answer (score 0):

[Bounce Rate, specifically the Bounce Rate Metric in Google Analytics, is the percentage of single-page visits to total visits of a certain Dimension](http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/what-is-bounce-rate-in-google-analytics.html).  <---read this article, then read [what google has to say about it](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1006257).  Then use the help center in the lower left-hand corner of your analytics page to learn how to use analytics.

Answer (score 0):

It basically tells you what percentage of your visitors are “bouncing” away after landing on your site (e.g., they just visit one page and leave before clicking on to a second page inside your site).

Check Out it will give you clear picture: http://beyondgood.in/1308/bounce-rates-in-google-analytics/